# Table Column Alignment to HTML

Tags: tex4ht, html, xhtml

How to retain the LaTeX tabular cell alignment in the converted HTML **col** element?

For example:

```
\begin{tabular}{**lcr**}
```

should convert as

```
<col align="**left**" ..><col align="**centre**" ..><col align="**right**" ..>
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Are you sure that TeX.SE is the right place for this query? Could you maybe make your query more specific to the machinery of `tex4ht`?

Comment: The colum alignment should be specified using CSS, which is what TeX4ht does. The align attribute is depcated in HTML. Do you really need that? It should be possible, bu probably not a good idea.

Comment: @michal.h21: i am converting TeX to XHTML to XML to compile the XML file using XMLTeX, in this case, I want to retain the LaTeX table alignment as is in the col element so I can map the same alignment to XML will match the Source TeX table alignment. Hope this helps.

Comment: @Mico: Thank You Mico. Ok noted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this configuration file:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}

\Configure{halignTD}
{}{}
{^}{\HCode{style="vertical-align:top"}}
{=}{\HCode{style="vertical-align:baseline"}}
{|}{\HCode{style="vertical-align:middle"}}
{_}{\HCode{style="vertical-align:bottom"}}
{<}{\HCode{align="left"}}
{-}{\HCode{align="center"}}
{>}{\HCode{align="right"}}
{p}{\HCode{align="left"}}
{}

\catcode`\:=11
\Configure{VBorder}
   {\let\VBorder\empty \let\AllColMargins\empty
    \global\let\GROUPS\empty \HAssign\NewGroup = 0
    \gHAdvance\Next:TableNo by 1 \global\let\TableNo=\Next:TableNo }
   {\xdef\VBorder{\VBorder\ifnum \NewGroup> 0 </colgroup>\fi}
    \HAssign\NewGroup = 0 % \gdef\GROUPS{rules="groups"}}
    % put vertical border for a column
    \ifnum\ar:cnt > 0%
      % in all other cases, we should put right border
      \Css{\#TBL-\TableNo-\ar:cnt {border-right:1px solid black;}}%
    \else%
      % columns are numbered from 1. if \ar:cnt == 0 then it is the left border
      \Css{\#TBL-\TableNo-1{border-left: 1px solid black;}}%
    \fi%
   }
   {\Advance:\NewGroup by 1
    \ifnum \NewGroup=1 \xdef\VBorder{\VBorder<colgroup
        id="TBL-\TableNo-\ar:cnt g">}\fi
    \bgroup\def\HCode##1{##1} % we need to redefine \HCode locally, otherwise we would get spurious characters inside the HTML tag
    \xdef\VBorder{\VBorder<col\Hnewline id="TBL-\TableNo
       -\ar:cnt" \HColAlign \xml:empty>}
   \egroup
   \xdef\AllColMargins{\AllColMargins1}}
   {\xdef\AllColMargins{\AllColMargins 0}}
\catcode`\:=12
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

First, it defines that instead of CSS styles, `align` attributes should be used for table column alignment specifications. This is done in `\Configure{halignTD}`. You can add all possible table specifiers here.

But this will ensure insertion of `align` attributes only to particular table cells, but not into the `<col>` elements as you want. To do that, we need to put the `\HColAlign` command into the code of `\Configure{VBorder}`.

For this MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|l|c|r|}
  hello & world & right \\
  longer & words should & show something
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

This is the result:

[image]

```html
<div class='tabular'> 
<table class='tabular' id='TBL-1'>
<colgroup id='TBL-1-1g'><col align='left' id='TBL-1-1' /></colgroup>
<colgroup id='TBL-1-2g'><col align='center' id='TBL-1-2' /></colgroup>
<colgroup id='TBL-1-3g'><col align='right' id='TBL-1-3' /></colgroup>
<tr id='TBL-1-1-' style='vertical-align:baseline;'><td align='left' class='td11' id='TBL-1-1-1'>hello </td><td align='center' class='td11' id='TBL-1-1-2'>   world     </td><td align='right' class='td11' id='TBL-1-1-3'>         right</td></tr>
<tr id='TBL-1-2-' style='vertical-align:baseline;'><td align='left' class='td11' id='TBL-1-2-1'>longer</td> <td align='center' class='td11' id='TBL-1-2-2'>words should</td> <td align='right' class='td11' id='TBL-1-2-3'>show something</td> </tr>
</table>                                                
</div>
```

Comment: Brilliant!!! 

But, when i add the above **halignTD** coding math coding got disturbed,

All my math in XHTML was included with style="vertical-align:top" and other attributes. 

Refer below piece of html code: 

 (\Omega ,\mathcal}{\HCode{style="vertical-align:middle"}}F},\mathbb}{\HCode{style="vertical-align:middle"}}P}) 

So i removed valign attributes then its working fine since i don't want valign.

Comment: @RampSmart can you update your question with the full sample document, so I can see what is going on with the math? It is hard to understand it from the small snippet in your comment.

Comment: After adding the halignTD in cfg file Below TeX Code:

Let
 $T\in (0,\infty)$ be a given terminal time,
$(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ be a complete  probability space
on which a  $d$-dimensional Brownian motion $W=(W_t)_{t\in [0,T]}$
is defined,
 ${\mathbb{F}} $ be the natural filtration

Comment: In XHTML Converted as:

Let <in-math id="1">T\in (0,\infty )</in-math> be a given terminal time, <in-math id="2">(\Omega ,\mathcal}{\HCode{style="vertical-align:middle"}}F},\mathbb}{\HCode{style="vertical-align:middle"}}P})</in-math> be a complete probability space on which a <in-math id="3">d</in-math>-dimensional Brownian motion <in-math id="4">W=(W_t)_}{\HCode{style="vertical-align:middle"}}t\in [0,T]}</in-math> is defined, <in-math id="5">}{\HCode{style="vertical-align:middle"}}\mathbb}{\HCode{style="vertical-align:middle"}}F}} </in-math> be the natural filtration

Comment: @RampSmart sorry, I cannot reproduce it in this way. I need a full document that I can copy and compile. And also the command line options that you use for the compilation.

Comment: catcode that was defined in my package created the problem, my bad, I corrected now it's converting fine, Thanks for the great support.

Comment: @RampSmart ah, that can happen. I am glad it wasn't something more serious.